# How do I parse JSON data and save it my postgresql table?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, postgresql

I have a python file and multiple JSON files(Around 20 files) in my directory. I have a postgresql schema defined as well. How do I Parse the json files and store the values in my Postgresql table?
Here is my schema .sql file

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS node_data_table (
    id AUTOINCREMENT,
    block_producer_key VARCHAR,
    recieved_at timestamp,
    online_status BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
    added_time timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY(block_producer_key, recieved_at)

);
```

And here is my python file.

```
import json
import glob
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

db_name = 'playground'
db_user = 'postgres'
db_pass = 'username@1'
db_host = 'db'
db_port = '5432'

db_string = 'postgres://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(db_user, db_pass, db_host, db_port, db_name)
db = create_engine(db_string)
for filename in glob.glob("2021-03-05.*.json"):
    with open(filename) as json_data:
        data = json.load(json_data)
        columns = list(data.keys())
        print('Column names', columns)
```

The output:

```
Column names ['receivedAt', 'receivedFrom', 'blockProducerKey']
```

What I am trying to do here is getting a list of column names. I want values under these column names to be stored in the postgresql database. How do I do that? I am aware that it needs to be dumped using `json.dumps` but how do I intereact with the postgresql database? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you already have an sqlachemy engine. You could just use a connection and insert your data:

```
db = create_engine(db_string)
conn = db.connect()
with conn.begin():                             # use a single transaction
    for filename in glob.glob("2021-03-05.*.json"):
        with open(filename) as json_data:
            data = json.load(json_data)
            conn.execute("""INSERT INTO node_data_table (block_producer_key,recieved_at)
                            VALUES(:block_producer_key, :recieved_at)""",
                         {k, v for k,v in data.items() if k in ('block_producer_key',
                                                                'recieved_at')})
```

Comment: hi thanks for your quick response, There is however a syntax error at {k, v for k,v in data.items if k in ('block_producer_key',

Comment: @technophile_3:I forgot the parens after `items`... Fixed.

Comment: That ran however it crashed into [SQL: INSERT INTO node_data_table (block_producer_key,recieved_at)
                            VALUES(:block_producer_key, :recieved_at)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no PostgreSQL database at hand. I only simulated with a SQLite one which has different semantics. After reading again the declaration, I think that the received_at value should be converted into a datetime object.

Comment: I changed a few things and I am able to do it. Thanks alot